# Transistor choice for PWM controlled LCD backlight

Tags: transistors, stm32, bjt, lcd, backlight

I have a problem with choosing most appropriate transistor to control backlight of my LCD display. According to datasheet its \$I_f = 60mA\$, and  \$V_f = 3.2V\$. My circuitry is all 3.3V based. I want to supply PWM signal from my STM32 F411CEU6, but it can only supply max of 25mA per GPIO pin. Due to rather large \$V_f\$ there is not a lot of space left for Current limiting resistor, and \$V_{DS}\$ or \$V_{CE}\$. I have found 2SC5585TL NPN BJT ([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_ROHM-Semicon-2SC5585TL_C337983.pdf)). According to it, if I were to supply 6mA at Base (\$\frac{I_C}{I_B} = \frac{60mA}{6mA} = 10\$) \$V_{CE}\$ should be around 25mV, which leaves 75mV for current limiting resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyp3te.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will this work as intended? Are my calculations correct? What is the preferred transistor type here BJT, or MOSFET?

Comment: Do you have any higher voltage available? For example, the 3.3 V might have been derived from a 5 V supply. The backlight probably doesn't need a tightly regulated supply, so the 3.3 V regulator would have an easier life.

Comment: @AndrewMorton unfortunately I only have 3.3V power supply available at the moment. What do you mean by „tightly regulated supply”?

Comment: A tightly-regulated supply would not have much voltage ripple.